# The keyboard hides textfield, if pickerVew's window opened

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, textfield

I have tableview with two textfields and one Image pickerView button.
[image]

If I write something, my textfields are upping, and **it's okay.**

[image]

But, if I choose photo from my imagePicker view and try to write something, I don't see my textfields. Please, help.

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to slide the scroll up for the text fields?

Comment: Hello, @MatthewSeaman,
Thank you for comment. I don't use any code to do this.

Comment: So you just have a `UIScrollView` and when the keyboard comes up the scrollview automatically scrolls up without you doing anything? Except immediately after you choose an image from an image picker?

Comment: @MatthewSeaman, correctly, when I choose something from imagePicker and try to use my textfield, my UIScrollView doesn't move.

Comment: Check the delegate methods for uiscrollview. It has methods to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}


deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size.height {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```